# What is the difference between a Summit and an Apex?

Tags: word-usage

Summit, Peak, and Apex are often interchanged. What is the difference between Summit vs Apex or Peak vs Summit

Comment: @J.R.: Summit and apex are also used outside of topographical or geographical context. Maybe the question is probing in that direction.

Comment: @Key - I'd like to see the question probe in that direction – or any direction.

Answer (score 0):

According to these definitions, they are completely interchangeable:

**Peak** -

> the highest level or greatest degree

**Summit** -

> the highest point

**Apex** -

> the uppermost point

Comment: I don't think you can refer to the apex of a turn as the summit of the turn.

Comment: "Peak" also has unique usages.  "He peaked too early."

Comment: You say, *"According to these definitions"*.  Where did you find these definitions? Did you write them yourself? If you copied them from somewhere, please acknowledge the source and, if possible, give us a link so that we can check the correctness, authority and completeness of the definitions. Thanks.